# SOQL Where Statement that Always Evaluates to False

Tags: soql

I am generating a SOQL statement dynamically and under certain conditions I want the query to return 0 results.

The best/most concise way that I could come up with to do this is by appending an `Id = null` to my query clause as follows:

```
select Id, Name from Contact where Id = null
```

Is this the best way to guarantee a query with 0 results?

The reason I ask is because in `SQL` you can add an arbitrary comparison of numbers such a `1 = 0`, but this does not seem to work with `SOQL`.

Comment: Does `where 1=0` work?

Comment: @WernerCD - it works with SQL (i.e. MS SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL), but not SOQL based on my findings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes `Id=null` is the shortest possible filter which will never return results.

Comment: For all *normal* tables, anyways. There's a few tables that actually do have Id values that are all null.

Comment: @sfdcfox Which tables can be queried with SOQL and have null Id values?

Comment: @sfdcfox - im curious too

Answer (score 9):

In addition to `Id = null`, you can instead use the somewhat clearer `limit 0` (similar to `top 0` in SQL, but goes at the end of the query like `select Id, Name from Contact Limit 0`).

Answer (score 2):

There are other attribute checking I could think of beside `Id= null` are as follows:

- `OwnerId = null`
- `CreatedById = null`
- `CreatedDate = null`

Comment: OwnerId won't work for detail objects in master-detail relationships, and while CreatedById and CreatedDate are theoretically safe, but might fail in extraordinary ways in really, really old orgs.